# Is the Nginx repo the same as the Ubuntu 18.04 repo?

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-18.04, repo

I have installed Nginx using the following repo:

```
deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu bionic nginx
```

I now need to install Phusion Passenger which is telling me that unless I have installed from the official Ubuntu repo I will need to recompile the Passenger module etc.

I have tried to find where IF ANY is the Ubuntu 'official' repo for Nginx, and not succeeded.

How can I find the 'official' Ubuntu 18.04 Nginx repo?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bionic repo should be

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic
```

After which you should put your categories (like `main` `multiverse`..)

Web url here: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/

You probably want `nginx-full` from universe

https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/nginx-full

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe
```

This random forum post from ubuntuforums has a good post on what the full contents of your sources.lst should be and a sources generator: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2398031#post13789955

Comment: Thanks very much for your prompt response.  I guess I have to uninstall and then reinstall from the above repo.  Ah well at least I know which direction I'm heading.

Comment: Minor correction: Ubuntu repository is _downsteam_, not upstream. Upstream are the original software authors (i.e., nginx.org), downstream are the distros, such as Ubuntu, that take the original software, patch/modify and package it.

Comment: @MestreLion woops, you're right! updated

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to the accepted answer:

Whenever you're told to install from the "official Ubuntu repositories", this usually simply means installing using `apt`:

```
sudo apt install nginx
```

Which, unless you added extra repositories by editing `/etc/apt/sources.list` or adding files to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, will grab the packages from the default repositories of your Ubuntu release.

If you want to check which repository `apt` will pick when installing a package, use `policy`:

```
apt policy nginx
```

In a default Ubuntu 18.04 system this will output something like this:

```
nginx:
  Installed: 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.10
  Candidate: 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.10
  Version table:
 *** 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.10 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.14.0-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
```